# How to download tortoise svn client for ubuntu 14.04

Tags: 14.04, svn

Ho w to download tortoise svn client  for ubuntu 14.04

Answer (score 1):

I'm afraid that Tortoise SVN is not available for Ubuntu.

You may want to try RabbitVCS which was inspired by Tortoise.

[RabbitVCS](http://rabbitvcs.org/)